# How to run a wxPython GUI app in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, wxpython, sublimetext2

I just started to use Sublime Text 2.

I use Sublime for python, but when I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> it does not run my wxPython GUI app. It *can* run a Tkinter app.

Why is this? What do I need to do to run a wxPython app from Sublime?

Comment: Can you run the same application from shell?

Comment: CTRL+B can create Tkinter GUI app

Comment: can you run your wx app without errors from shell?

Comment: like this [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4334),use other shell can run wx app

Answer (score 13):

To prevent the console window from popping up under Windows, it is suppressed in the `Packages\Default\exec.py` module. An unfortunate side effect is that wxPython gui's are also suppressed.

Just comment out the last line in the following section of the `Packages\Default\exec.py` file like so:

```py
if os.name == "nt":
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    #startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the file named python.sublime-build under C:\Users[USER NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\

Add the following value **"shell":"true"**
Save the file and run your How to run a wxPython GUI app in Sublime Text 2!

Answer (score 0):

The action of comment this line actually works:

```
if os.name == "nt":
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    #startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

The only diference in Window at this moment is the path, 
the correct path to found the "exec.py" file is:

```
 C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Default
```